# trying to do a fresh install or RoR and I'm getting all sorts of issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, terminal

I previously used a package installer from railsinstaller.org to set up an installation of Rails on my Mac OS X system. There's always been the odd problem, but nothing major.  I decided to delete it completely and start again, but now I'm seeing more problems.

Is it worth completely deleting my installations of Git, Homebrew, Ruby and anything else that you might recommend, and just starting again perhaps?

Here's the problem I'm getting when typing into terminal:

```
$ rvm reinstall 1.9.3

device-3ebf56 local (master)*: brew doctor
Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:

    /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/curl-config
    /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/ncurses5-config
    /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/ncursesw5-config
    /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/pkg-config
    /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/xml2-config
    /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/xslt-config

Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libosxfuse_i32.2.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libosxfuse_i64.2.dylib

Warning: Unbrewed .la files were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .la files:
    /usr/local/lib/libosxfuse_i32.la
    /usr/local/lib/libosxfuse_i64.la

Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files:
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/osxfuse.pc

Warning: /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin
This means that system-provided programs will be used instead of those
provided by Homebrew. The following tools exist at both paths:

    clusterdb
    createdb
    createlang
    createuser
    dropdb
    droplang
    dropuser
    ecpg
    git
    git-cvsserver
    git-receive-pack
    git-shell
    git-upload-archive
    git-upload-pack
    gitk
    pg_basebackup
    pg_config
    pg_dump
    pg_dumpall
    pg_restore
    pg_upgrade
    psql
    reindexdb
    vacuumdb

Consider setting your PATH so that /usr/local/bin
occurs before /usr/bin. Here is a one-liner:
    echo export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile
device-3ebf56 local (master)*: echo export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.basdevice-3ebf56 local (master)*: echo export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

---

EDIT:

Thank you both for your replies.

I have no idea what I'm doing.

I tried running the remove homebrew code and then I got the following error. I thought it had uninstalled so I tried reinstalling it but then was told it's still there, so I tried reinstalling it. I hope this makes sense:

```
Last login: Fri Sep 27 18:03:54 on ttys000
-bash: __rvm_add_to_path: command not found
env: node: No such file or directory
device-3ebf56 ~: ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"It appears Homebrew is already installed. If your intent is to reinstall you
should do the following before running this installer again:
    rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup
device-3ebf56 ~:
device-3ebf56 ~:
device-3ebf56 ~: rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup
-bash: brew: command not found
device-3ebf56 ~:
```

Comment: You're having problems with Homebrew. I suggest you remove your Homebrew installation completely by using the code in this link: https://gist.github.com/mxcl/1173223 And then proceed by reinstalling Homebrew first. Only go forward with RVM once you get the message `Your system is ready to brew` after running `brew doctor`.

Comment: @depa `brew doctor` really is amazing. Also [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) seems to work better than RVM these days.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies.

I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: I've just tried that and added something in my original post under "edit". Ty

Comment: You need to take time to learn how to format your questions. As is, you're mixing your text and code and keyboard so it's hard to read.

Comment: "I have no idea what I'm doing.". OK, this is a key phrase. Take the time to research carefully before making changes to your system. In particular, be VERY careful when you have to enter any commands using `sudo` or that ask for your password. Even if the command isn't malicious, one mistyped character can take out your machine once a command is running as the system administrator, which is what `sudo` allows. When you follow instructions on a website, make sure they're current. Sites that are a couple years old are rarely accurate given the speed of change in computers.